# wp_enqueue_style built in styles

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, api, css

I'm writing (rewriting) my plugin to use

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
```

**Which is great!**

But to use the dialog I need to load a jquery style sheet with wp_enqueue_style, is there a way to load a built-in style, similar to the way you can load the built in scripts (as seen above)? Or do I need to make a call to an external resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, can you not simply use [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), given you mentioned it in the title of the question.

The `wp_enqueue_style` function works in the same way as the [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) counterpart, but as you'd expect, enqueues stylesheets in place of scripts.

Here's a list of the enqueues i was able to find in WordPress core, styles you can load without needing to register them or declare paths to (updated for 6.0 - holy post update batman!).

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_style('colors');
wp_enqueue_style('common');
wp_enqueue_style('forms');
wp_enqueue_style('admin-menu');
wp_enqueue_style('dashboard');
wp_enqueue_style('list-tables');
wp_enqueue_style('edit');
wp_enqueue_style('revisions');
wp_enqueue_style('media');
wp_enqueue_style('themes');
wp_enqueue_style('about');
wp_enqueue_style('nav-menus');
wp_enqueue_style('widgets');
wp_enqueue_style('site-icon');
wp_enqueue_style('l10n');
wp_enqueue_style('code-editor');
wp_enqueue_style('site-health');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-admin');
wp_enqueue_style('login');
wp_enqueue_style('install');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-color-picker');
wp_enqueue_style('customize-controls');
wp_enqueue_style('customize-widgets');
wp_enqueue_style('customize-nav-menus');
wp_enqueue_style('buttons');
wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');
wp_enqueue_style('admin-bar');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-auth-check');
wp_enqueue_style('editor-buttons');
wp_enqueue_style('media-views');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-pointer');
wp_enqueue_style('customize-preview');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-embed-template-ie');
wp_enqueue_style('imgareaselect');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_enqueue_style('mediaelement');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-mediaelement');
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror');
wp_enqueue_style('deprecated-media');
wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');
wp_enqueue_style('jcrop');
wp_enqueue_style('colors-fresh');
wp_enqueue_style('open-sans');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-editor-font');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-library-theme');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-editor-classic-layout-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-blocks');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-editor');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-library');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-block-directory');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-components');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-post');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-editor');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-format-library');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-list-reusable-blocks');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-reusable-blocks');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-nux');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-widgets');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-widgets');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-customize-widgets');
wp_enqueue_style('wp-edit-site');
?>
```

Beyond using the styles listed above you'll need to declare a path inside your enqueue as it's not a registered style, like you would for scripts.

**Enqueue only**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'myPluginStylesheet', plugins_url( 'stylesheet.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

or..

**Register**

```
wp_register_style( 'myPluginStylesheet', plugins_url( 'stylesheet.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

**And call**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'myPluginStylesheet' );
```

For use on a single plugin page i'd skip the registration part and make a single enqueue call.

Hope that's the information you're looking for. :)

Comment: The list of style registrations is in [`wp_default_styles()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L400), it is little hard to fund because it uses object methods directly instead of wrapper enqueue function.

Comment: Good call.. i used a regex search in files to find the enqueues, took me no more time then it would to track that function down.. thanks though.. :)

Comment: so basically there is no default style for jQueryUI. I'll have to use Thickbox to blend in.

Comment: Just enqueue the stylesheets you need manually.. is there something in particular you're aiming for here that i'm missing?